# Passing in file extension Variable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to pass in the file extension as a variable but it doesn't seem to be working. when I run getlist.rb(txt)

```
def getlist(extension)
  file = File.new("the_list.txt", "w")
  Dir['../path/*.'+ extension].each { |f| file.puts File.basename(f, '.'+ extension).upcase }
end
```

Basically I want to drop in any file extension (txt, pdf, rb, etc) and it will give me the list without the extension names. Script works fine when it is hard coded just doesn't work when I try to drop in a variable.

Best Regards,

AZCards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example:

```
def getlist(extension)
  File.open("the_list.txt", "w"){|file|
    Dir["*.#{extension}"].each { |f| 
        file << File.basename(f, File.extname(f)).upcase
        file << "\n"
    }
  }
end

getlist('rb')
getlist(:rb)
```

My main modifications:

- File.open isnted new (you forgot file.close). With File.open and a block the close is done automatic.
- Replaces String+ with #-replacements. Advantage: you can use symbols when you call it (you wrote `getlist.rb(txt)` - this only works, when txt is a variable, but I think you want 'txt')
- Use File#extension., see Daves answer.
- I added newlines to the resulting file.

**Update**
Just in case you need a solution with multiple extensions and to call it from command line:

```
def getlist(*extensions)
  p "*.{#{extensions.join(',')}}"
  File.open("the_list.txt", "w"){|file|
    Dir["*.{#{extensions.join(',')}}"].each { |f| 
        file << File.basename(f, File.extname(f)).upcase
        file << "\n"
    }
  }
end

#getlist('rb', 'txt')
#getlist(:rb, :txt)
getlist(*ARGV)
```

Comment: This worked quite well, maybe this is a really newbie question, but how would I run getlist('rb') through the command line?  Tried it a few ways but nothing seemed to work. Be easier if I could pass the variable in that way rather than having it be coded in the getlist.rb file

Comment: I updated my answer. The constant ARGV contains all parameters from command line. After my change you can call it as `ruby getlist.rb txt rb` (getlist.rb is the script, txt and rb are the extensions (you can take as many extensions you want - also one)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir['../path/*.'+ extension].each { |f| file.puts File.basename(f, File.extname(f)).upcase }
```

That said, it works fine for me when using your original string concatenation, too:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :035 > getlist("html")
 => ["./about.html", "./epl-v10.html", "./notice.html"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :037 > getlist("*")
 => ["./libcairo-swt.so", "./eclipse.ini", "./icon.xpm", "./eclipse.ini~", "./about.html", "./epl-v10.html", "./artifacts.xml", "./notice.html"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :038 > getlist("ini")
 => ["./eclipse.ini"]
```

(Prints w/o extension removed for space purposes, but they print w/o the extension, in uppercase.)